# Dictionary Using Value Property as Key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Back around 2008 I was using a BCL dictionary that established the key based on a property of the obect-value that it was storing.  Now I can't find that dictionary.  Can someone remind me?  Here is what I recall about it:

- It required the class that was used as the <value> to implement an interface which had a method or property that identified which field/member was to be considered the key.
- It was a dictionary being used or defined in one of the ServiceModel namespaces.

I tried using a reflector tool to find all dictionary classes throughout the BCL, and I didn't spot it.  Perhaps the word "Dictionary" was not in the name of this magical class I had once been using.

Comment: Why not use the more modern `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: @JaredPar: Because it doesn't provide the specified behavior.

Comment: @BrentArias that may be true but perhaps you can achieve the same goal by using the .ToDictionary() method to create a Dictionary<K,V> with some degree of flexibility and no reflection perf hit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are remembering the `KeyedCollection<,>` abstract class? It established a key based on anything you want from the item.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Foo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class MyObjectCollection : KeyedCollection<string, MyObject>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(MyObject item)
    {
        return item.Key;
    }
}
```

In practice, I find LINQ's `ToDictionary()` to be more useful, though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, this is it.  I think the reason I thought it was in the "ServiceModel" namespace is perhaps because I first spotted KeyedCollection being used within the ServiceModel namespace.  My bad.